# how to control output of data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

For example, `uni = 1:10` when I try `data.frame(uni)`
I'm going to get:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

How can I get an output like

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

with 2 rows?

Comment: data.frame(uni) gives you a vertical list of 1 to 10. Not one row of 1 to 10. Please check your code before posting. It's disrespectful of others' time if your question ain't thought-through

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want one of these two:

```
matrix(uni, ncol = 2)
matrix(uni, nrow = 2, byrow = T)
```

Comment: thank you. eddi. is there any alternate way to use data.frame? since what I need is not making martix, but just expressing with data.frame, with same number of elements in a column.

Comment: if I understand what you're asking correctly - just use `as.data.frame(matrix(uni, ncol = 2))` to convert to a `data.frame`

Comment: sorry to confuse you, but the uni above is just an example. what I'm curious is just if I can output an result with limited nember of elements in a column with data.frame.

Comment: sorry I'm not following, you should try making a reproducible example of what you have and show what output you'd like to have